# Why we need Action Interface when all actions can be done with ActionsClass

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

If all actions can be performed using action class then where and why do we need Action Interface and what would be the explanation to it?

Method 1:-

```
WebElement Fname = driver.findElement(By.id("ts_first_name"));

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);

    Action newAct = act.moveToElement(Fname)
            .keyDown(Fname, Keys.SHIFT)
            .sendKeys("abhresh")
            .keyUp(Fname, Keys.SHIFT)
            .doubleClick(Fname)
            .contextClick(Fname)
            .build();

    newAct.perform();
```

Method 2:-

```
WebElement Fname = driver.findElement(By.id("ts_first_name"));

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);

    act.moveToElement(Fname)
            .keyDown(Fname, Keys.SHIFT)
            .sendKeys("abhresh")
            .keyUp(Fname, Keys.SHIFT)
            .doubleClick(Fname)
            .contextClick(Fname)
            .build().perform();
```

if both ways works the same then Why to use method 1? and why not?

Answer (score 2):

You are basically asking: what is the purpose of declaring that *local variable* `newAct` in example 1.

Answer is: it depends.

If you **only** need that Action object to invoke `perform()` on it, then there is **no** point in having that local variable. If, on the other hand, you want to do *other* things with `newAct` after calling `perform()`, then obviously, you better store that object so you can later access it.

In other words: you chose that method that you need to get your task done.  There is no right or wrong here, or good vs bad. Just two slightly different approaches that support two slightly different use cases.